# Error: Cannot find module 'stylelint' - Angular Project

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, sass, stylelint

I'm  trying to run this command to validate all the .scss (and even the .css files I tried too) and now it's presenting me with this error.

```
$ stylelint "apps/**/*.scss"
```

1 time it worked and no longer, I restarted the computer and still.

The stylelint is also globally installed and I have the latest version:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'stylelint'
Require stack:
- D:\DEV\Repos\Business\mobile-app-with-angular\node_modules\stylelint-order\index.js
- C:\Users\koalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylelint\lib\augmentConfig.js
- C:\Users\koalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylelint\lib\createStylelint.js
- C:\Users\koalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylelint\lib\printConfig.js
- C:\Users\koalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylelint\lib\cli.js
- C:\Users\koalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylelint\bin\stylelint.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:981:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
    at require (C:\Users\koalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylelint\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:161:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\DEV\Repos\Business\panama-mobile-app\node_modules\stylelint-order\index.js:1:88)
    at Module._compile (C:\Users\koalt\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\stylelint\node_modules\v8-compile-cache\v8-compile-cache.js:194:30)       
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1177:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1001:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:900:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1043:19)
```

From package.json:

```
"stylelint": "13.6.0",
"stylelint-config-standard": "20.0.0"
```

Thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: Have you tried to source it from node_modules with `npx stylelint "apps/**/*.scss"`?

Comment: @TomasVancoillie Yes, I have and it still fails.

Comment: Can you normally do some version check, like  `stylelint  --v / -v`  etc. does it shows same or similar error

Answer (score 0):

No, the reason is that in the **.stylelintrc.json** file I was referencing another extension of a package that did not exist (I had initially dealt with sass until I realized that using the standard is possible).

It was like this:

```
{
    "extends": "stylelint-config-sass-guidleines",
    ...
}
```

Now this was the modification and it worked:

```
{
    "extends": "stylelint-config-standard",
    ...
}
```

Many thanks!